# I want tkinter asksaveasfile() to save as utf-8 in python. How can I solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, save-as

I wrote the following code in Python:

```
sveas = f.asksaveasfile()
sveas.write(f'{code.get(1.0,END)}')
sveas.close()
```

Here I want it to encode the file with utf-8. how can i solve

Comment: ++++++++++++++++

Comment: `asksaveasfilename()` is used in the question title, but `saveasfile()` is used inside the posted code.  Which one is used in your actual code?

Comment: @acw1668 asksaveasfile()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the encoding type, you need to pass `encoding='utf-8'` when you open the file.  Since `asksaveasfile()` will open the file implicitly for you but you cannot specify the encoding type, so `asksaveasfilename()` need to be used instead and then you open the selected file using `open()` explicitly:

```py
filename = f.asksaveasfilename()
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    fh.write(code.get('1.0', END))
```